# Iterate over particular json

Tags: javascript, iteration, json

i need to iterate in js(no framework) over a json object generated in php with the follow structure:

```
    {
        EDITED: I DID HAVE AN ERROR, SORRY
    }
```

I search for a solution without any js framework.
¿how to get, for example,

```
lvl1a.lvl2a.a
lvl1a.lvl2a.b
lvl1a.lvl2b.a
lvl1a.lvl2b.b
...
```

?

Thanks

---

more information:

I DID HAVE AN ERROR IN PREV CODE!!! SORRY

Function: Populate two select, "select1" and "select2", with option=Category optgroup=CategoryParent

```
$toJson=array();
$selectname=array("select1","select2");
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){
    $sql="SELECT idCategory as v,name as l,(select name from categories where idCategory=C.idCategoryParent) as p FROM categories C WHERE idBanner".($i+1)." is NULL order by idCategoryParent, `order`";
    $result =$ocdb->query($sql);
    $nameIdx = "";
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $first=mysql_field_name($result, 0);
        $second=mysql_field_name($result,1);
        $third= mysql_field_name($result,2);            

        if($nameIdx!=$row[$third])
                $nameIdx=$row[$third];
        }
            if($row[$third]!=NULL){
                array_pop($row);
                $toJson[$selectname[$i]][$nameIdx][]=$row;
            }

    }

}
$inJson=json_encode($toJson);
```

So i get something like:

```
    {
        "select1":  {  "optgroup1":[{"v":"1","l":"option1"},{"v":"2","l":"option2"}],
                       "optgroup2":[{"v":"3","l":"option1"},{"v":"4","l":"option2"}],
                       "optgroup3":[{"v":"5","l":"option1"},{"v":"6","l":"option2"}]
                    },
        "select2":  {  " (...)
    }
```

//optgroup is parentCategory
//options are categories no-parents

Comment: You have to provide more information. How do you have access to the data from JavaScript? I.e. do you retrieve via Ajax, or is your PHP script actually generating the JavaScript and inserting the data into it? Generally speaking, you cannot really traverse any JSON data, because it is just a textual representation. You can *convert* it to a JavaScript object though and then simply access its properties as you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something recursive:

```
function iterateObject(obj){
  var result = [];

  function recurse(obj){
     for (var l in obj){
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(l)){
       result.push( l+ 
                    (!(obj[l] instanceof Object) 
                     ? ': '+obj[l] 
                     : ' -> object >' ));
       if (obj[l] instanceof Object){
          recurse(obj[l]);
       }
      }
     }
  }

  recurse(obj);
  return result;
}

var thing = {
    "lvl1a":  {  "lvl2a":[{"a":"xxxxx"},{"b":"xxxxx"}],
                 "lvl2b":[{"a":"xxxxx"},{"b":"xxxxx"}],
                 "lvl2c":[{"a":"xxxxx"},{"b":"xxxxx"}]
              },
    "lvl1b":  {  "lvl3a":[{"c":"xxxxx"},{"d":"xxxxx"}],
                 "lvl3b":[{"c":"xxxxx"},{"d":"xxxxx"}],
                 "lvl3c":[{"c":"xxxxx"},{"d":"xxxxx"}]
              }
};
console.log(iterateObject(thing).join('\n'));
//=> 
// lvl1a -> object >
// lvl2a -> object >
// 0 -> object >
// a: xxxxx
// 1 -> object >
// b: xxxxx
// ... etc
```

Comment: Very useful. You help me a lot! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You mean:

```
myObject.lvl1a.lvl2a[0].a
myObject.lvl1a.lvl2a[1].b
```

and so on?